# sticky session nginx for limited time

Tags: nginx, session, sticky

I'm trying to implement sticky sessions in Nginx for a limited time based on a cookie generated by a Python application. In the nginx.conf file, I know I can use ip_hash to ensure that I stay on the same server. However, I need to remain on the same server for only 1 minute before being directed to a different server.

Answer (score 0):

Use the nginx [sticky](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_upstream_module.html#sticky) directive.

For example:

```
upstream backend {
    server backend1.example.com;
    server backend2.example.com;

    sticky cookie srv_id expires=1h domain=.example.com path=/;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. 
I can't use "Nginx Plus" features.